# is there any way to get all photos from gallery prophetically using objective-c code?

Tags: iphone, ios

i have to fetch all photos from the iphone gallery **without** open the imagepickercontroller. if any have any idea or reference then post here and help me to complete my task.

Thanks in advance

Ravi

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ALAssetsLibrary` for that. Keep in mind that users have to grant your application access to the location services to be able to "read" the items in your library. Try this piece of code and let me know if it works:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock successBlock =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (result != nil) {
                // do something with your asset
            }
        }];
    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Could not enumarate assets. Reason: %@", error);
};

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:successBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
[library release];
```

You can also read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details. Also, don't forget to add `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` in your `.h` file and link the `AssetsLibrary.framework` to your project before.

Let me know if that helps!